# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci, pundit

I have a new model, this is my migration:

```
def change
    create_table :news do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

and this is my schema

```
  create_table "news", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

I also have a policy (from pundit) for this model and a new_policy_test, however, at the moment both are empty.

So when passing the tests in Travis it tells me:

```
NewPolicyTest#test_update:
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, MyString, MyText, null, null).
```

and the same for NewPolicyTest#test_update, NewPolicyTest#test_scope, NewPolicyTest#test_show, NewPolicyTest#test_destroy, NewPolicyTest#test_create.

What should I do for Travis not to give me this error?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.  When the column values are null in non-nullable columns, you get a NotNullViolation -- that is the expected behavior.

Comment: My question is what should I do in order to not get ```ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:```

Comment: Edit your post to say that.

Comment: from which line of code you are getting this error, can you share that too

Comment: I've solved it by editing the fixtures on my news.yml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added created_at and updated_at fixtures to my news.yml file.

```
one:
  title: MyString
  content: MyText
  created_at: <%= 5.day.ago.to_s(:db) %>
  updated_at: <%= 5.day.ago.to_s(:db) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have

t.timestamps

in your migration instead of

t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false

it will then populate the fields automatically when a record is created or updated.

Comment: In my migration I have t.timestamps, the code snippet I have is from my schema

Answer (score 0):

One reason this happens is when the model name is plural like in the question (model `News` for table `news`).

The solution to this is to update `config/initializers/inflections.rb` with:

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "news"
end
```